# pandas long to wide without multi-dimensional table

Tags: pandas

I have a table that looks like this. The full sample code and source data is at the bottom, including two answers provided.

```
           id   technology     question  response
0        subj1  technology1       Q1         3  
1        subj1  technology2       Q1         4
...
10       subj1  technology3      Q3          6
11       subj1  technology4       Q3         2
12       subj1  technology4       Q4         7
13       subj1  technology3       Q4         5
14       subj1  technology1       Q4         5
15       subj1  technology2       Q4         9
16       subj2  technology2       Q1         1
17       subj2  technology1       Q1         4
...
29       subj2  technology3       Q4         0
```

What I want is a table where the different values of the 'question' column become columns in their own right, and where the value in the question column cell is the response value for the given question for the given subject and technology, like this (just an illustration):

```
         id      technology      Q1 Q2  Q3  Q4
0        subj1  technology1      3  3   2   1
1        subj1  technology2      4  4   3   1
...
10       subj1  technology3      6  3   7   2
...
16       subj2  technology2      4  5   7   3
```

I can get close to that if I pivot the table like this (note the improved versions in the full code below, based on suggestions so far):

```
source_data_df_pvt1 = pd.pivot_table(source_data_df, index = ['id'],  
                                    columns = ['technology', 'question'], 
                                    values = 'response', aggfunc='first')
```

Which gives me this multi-dimensional dataframe:

```
technology technology1                   technology2                      technology3                technology4                technology5
question            Q1   Q2    Q3     Q4          Q1    Q2   Q3    Q4            Q1  Q2   Q3    Q4          Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4          Q1
id                                                                                                                                     
subj1              3.0   9.0   7.0   5.0         4.0   5.0  3.0   9.0           3.0  8.0  6.0  5.0         5.0  8.0  2.0  7.0         NaN
subj2              4.0   9.0   8.0   7.0         1.0   5.0  8.0  20.0        20.0  9.0  4.0  0.0         3.0  0.0  8.0  6.0         NaN
subj3             14.0   NaN  10.0   0.0         NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        15.0
subj4             13.0   4.0   5.0  11.0        17.0   NaN  NaN   NaN         0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN         0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN         NaN
subj5              3.0  20.0   4.0   8.0         2.0  20.0  3.0   2.0         3.0  5.0  7.0  5.0         4.0  2.0  7.0  5.0         NaN
subj6              2.0   8.0   1.0   6.0         0.0   7.0  4.0   1.0        20.0  6.0  1.0  0.0         6.0  8.0  7.0  3.0         NaN
```

I don't want my dataframe to be mult-dimensional though, I just want a single dimension table.

Is this possible with Pandas?

Full sample code and output, including working solutions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

#See https://gist.github.com/NathanDotTo/e506c1946c23234d2c24a2bd27e570a0#file-technology_skills-csv
sample_data = "../test_data/technology_skills.csv"

#The sample data has these columns:
column_names = ["id", "technology", "question", "response"]

source_data_df = pd.read_csv(sample_data, names = column_names, header = None)

#Change response to be numeric
pd.to_numeric(source_data_df.response)

#Strip white spaces from questions
source_data_df['question'] = source_data_df['question'].str.strip()

#Pivot the table to create columns from response values for each question     

source_data_df_pvt1 = pd.pivot_table(source_data_df, index = ['id','technology'],  
                                columns = [ 'question'], 
                                values = 'response', 
                                aggfunc='first',
                                fill_value=np.nan).reset_index()

print('source_data_df_pvt1 *******************')
print (source_data_df_pvt1)

source_data_df_pvt2 = source_data_df.pivot_table(index=['id','technology'],
                                 columns='question',
                                 values='response',
                                 aggfunc='sum',
                                 fill_value=np.nan).reset_index()

print('source_data_df_pvt2 *******************')
print (source_data_df_pvt2)
```

The results are below:

```
source_data_df_pvt1 *******************
question     id   technology  Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
0         subj1  technology1   3   9.0   7.0   5.0
1         subj1  technology2   4   5.0   3.0   9.0
2         subj1  technology3   3   8.0   6.0   5.0
3         subj1  technology4   5   8.0   2.0   7.0
4         subj2  technology1   4   9.0   8.0   7.0
5         subj2  technology2   1   5.0   8.0  20.0
6         subj2  technology3  20   9.0   4.0   0.0
7         subj2  technology4   3   0.0   8.0   6.0
8         subj3  technology1  14   NaN  10.0   0.0
9         subj3  technology5  15   NaN   NaN   NaN 
10        subj4  technology1  13   4.0   5.0  11.0
11        subj4  technology2  17   NaN   NaN   NaN
12        subj4  technology3   0   NaN   NaN   NaN
13        subj4  technology4   0   NaN   NaN   NaN
14        subj5  technology1   3  20.0   4.0   8.0
15        subj5  technology2   2  20.0   3.0   2.0
16        subj5  technology3   3   5.0   7.0   5.0
17        subj5  technology4   4   2.0   7.0   5.0
18        subj6  technology1   2   8.0   1.0   6.0
19        subj6  technology2   0   7.0   4.0   1.0
20        subj6  technology3  20   6.0   1.0   0.0
21        subj6  technology4   6   8.0   7.0   3.0

source_data_df_pvt2 *******************
question     id   technology  Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
0         subj1  technology1   3   9.0   7.0   5.0
1         subj1  technology2   4   5.0   3.0   9.0
2         subj1  technology3   3   8.0   6.0   5.0
3         subj1  technology4   5   8.0   2.0   7.0
4         subj2  technology1   4   9.0   8.0   7.0
5         subj2  technology2   1   5.0   8.0  20.0
6         subj2  technology3  20   9.0   4.0   0.0
7         subj2  technology4   3   0.0   8.0   6.0
8         subj3  technology1  14   NaN  10.0   0.0
9         subj3  technology5  15   NaN   NaN   NaN
10        subj4  technology1  13   4.0   5.0  11.0
11        subj4  technology2  17   NaN   NaN   NaN
12        subj4  technology3   0   NaN   NaN   NaN
13        subj4  technology4   0   NaN   NaN   NaN
14        subj5  technology1   3  20.0   4.0   8.0
15        subj5  technology2   2  20.0   3.0   2.0
16        subj5  technology3   3   5.0   7.0   5.0
17        subj5  technology4   4   2.0   7.0   5.0
18        subj6  technology1   2   8.0   1.0   6.0
19        subj6  technology2   0   7.0   4.0   1.0
20        subj6  technology3  20   6.0   1.0   0.0
21        subj6  technology4   6   8.0   7.0   3.0
```

As a bonus, this is what I wanted to be able to get to, in terms of simplicity of usage. It works the same for both pivot styles.

```
for row in source_data_df_pvt1.itertuples():
    print(row)
    print(row.id)
    print(row.technology)
    print(row.Q1)
    print(row.Q2)
    print(row.Q3)
    print(row.Q4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (source_data_df.set_index(['id','technology','question'])['response']
                   .unstack(fill_value=0)
                   .reset_index())
```

but if get error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means there are duplicates in triples `id`,`technology`,`question`, so is necessary remove duplicates or aggregate by `first`:

```
source_data_df = source_data_df.drop_duplicates(['id','technology','question'])
df = (source_data_df.set_index(['id','technology','question'])['response']
                   .unstack(fill_value=0)
                   .reset_index())
```

what is same as:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(source_data_df, index = ['id','technology'],  
                                    columns = [ 'question'], 
                                    values = 'response', 
                                    aggfunc='first',
                                    fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
question     id   technology  Q1  Q3  Q4
0         subj1  technology1   3   0   5
1         subj1  technology2   4   0   9
2         subj1  technology3   0   6   5
3         subj1  technology4   0   2   7
4         subj2  technology1   4   0   0
5         subj2  technology2   1   0   0
6         subj2  technology3   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you, please updated question where I have tried this. It did not quite seem to work.

Comment: There is problem column `question` contains sometimes trailing whitespaces, so there are `'Q3'` and `'Q3 '`. So need first `df['question'] = df['question'].str.strip()` for remove them.

Comment: I really should have spotted those spaces, thank you. The question has been updated with the full working code.